# Replace string ${FOO} by ${'$'}{BAR} with sed

Tags: sed, quoting

I have this string occurring N times in a file: `${FOO}`
that I have to replace by this string: `${'$'}{BAR}`

This is my current state:

`sed "s/\\${FOO}/\\${'\\$'}{BAR}/" file.txt` but it raises "bad substitution".

How could I properly achieve that with `sed` (version 4.8) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single backslash before the dollar sign is enough.

```bash
$ echo '${FOO} xxx ${FOO} xxx ${FOO}' | sed "s/\${FOO}/\${'\$'}{BAR}/g"
${'$'}{BAR} xxx ${'$'}{BAR} xxx ${'$'}{BAR}
```

Using single quotes is also a possibility. It simplifies the dollar signs, but the single quotes become a bit more complex:

```bash
echo '${FOO} xxx ${FOO} xxx ${FOO}' | sed 's/${FOO}/${'\''$'\''}{BAR}/g'
```

Comment: or `sed 's/${FOO}/${\x27$\x27}{BAR}/g'`